# Suggest some useful techniques to reduce the size of a CNN architecture?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Context: I am going to start training a CNN to classify a data set. This CNN will have to be deployed for a real world application. So a forward propagation through this CNN has to be fast. Most of the CNN architectures I have read cannot run without a GPU and need a lot of costly resources to be deployed.

Question:
Now I know one particular technique that's quite useful for reducing the size of a CNN architecture: Downsize the image using cubic interpolation ( Cubic interpolation helps improve certain image features like edges ). This helps reduce the number of convolution layers as well as the filter size thus reducing the overall parameters in a CNN by quite a lot. I wanted to know if there are other techniques which can make a CNN smaller so that it can be realistically deployed.

Answer (score 1):

Binarization techniques are effective algorithms which allow to constrain both the parameters and the activations of a network to have binary values. Obviously the precision loss may degrade a bit the final performances, but the binary representation reduces a lot the resource requirements of the network.

For instance, you can have a look at these works:

- [Binarized Neural Networks](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/6573-binarized-neural-networks.pdf)
- [Binarized Neural Networks: Training Neural Networks with Weights and Activations Constrained to +1 or −1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.02830)
- [XNOR-Net: ImageNet Classification Using Binary
  Convolutional Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.05279.pdf)

which released their code.